# Entity Framework Many-to-Many not loading related entities

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I have to 2 entity classes with a many-to-many relationship defined via FluentAPI. Entity1 has the virtual collection with the related Entity2-objects. Entity2 does NOT have this collection since I dont need it. 
My classes look like this:

```
  internal class Franchisee : UserAccount //abstract base class with more properties
  {
        public virtual ICollection<FranchiseOffice> FranchiseOffices { get; set; } 
  }

  internal class FranchiseOffice: Office //abstract base class
  {
        <many properties, but no collection for Franchisee-objects>
  }
```

Configuration of the many-to-many relationship:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CoreModel, Migrations.Configuration>());

            //many-to-many relationship with only one navigation property
            modelBuilder.Entity<Franchisee>().HasMany(u => u.FranchiseOffices).WithMany().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("FranchiseeId");
                m.MapRightKey("FranchiseOfficeId");
                m.ToTable("FranchiseOffices");
            });
  }
```

**What is working**: saving the entities and linking them together via the navigation property. Data in the database looks fine; the mapping table 'FranchiseOffices' is there and filled with data.

**What does not work**: when I load a Franchisee, the collection 'FranchiseOffices' is NULL although data is present for it in the database.

The only difference to online examples I can see is that I am using inherited classes on both sides. I tried querying the child-classes explicity, but the outcome was the same. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "load" here *"when I load a Franchisee"* - are you asking EF to eager load the related collection, e.g. `Include(f => f.FranchiseOffices)`? If not and you are relying on lazy loading, is the lazy loading and proxy creation enabled for the context used to load the entity?

Comment: Well that did something. Lazy loading and proxy creation is turned on by default and doesn't seem to affect the outcome. However, manually using Include("FranchiseOffices") worked. Sadly, this is no solution for me for the following 2 reasons:
1. At query time, I do not know if the queried entity is of type "Franchisee" and thus cannot use the Include() (remember: Franchisee is a child-class).
2. Having to manually include all related entities in a many-to-many relationship is bad design; I'd like to find the root cause why EF is not automatically loading them. 
Thanks for helping though!

Comment: I have also tried adding the second navigation property on the other end; making it a "normal" many-to-many relationship. But the related entities were still not loaded automatically.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is the *lazy loading* that doesn't work. It would be nice if you provided that information in the question, along with reproducible example - for instance, are `UserAccount` and `Office` just base *classes* or they are base *entities* (i.e. part of one of the EF supported database inheritance strategies). Sample model, configuration and the non working query would help identifying the issue and seeking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I found the root cause :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan Stoev, I found the problem: all my entity classes were "internal" (and not "public" as per default). I wanted to keep them hidden inside the library since I use a conversion from entities to business objects before handing them to the outside. 
This made the following code neccessary:

```
  public CoreModel() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
  {
            //manually init the DbSets because they are 'internal' which prevents automatic init
            UserAccounts = Set<UserAccount>();
            Offices = Set<Office>();
   }
```

Since a many-to-many relatioship creates a separate mapping table, the explicit initialization of that table was missing which caused EF to miss out on the lazy loading of the related entities. Since I do not know how to initialize a table that I have no control over, I simply made all entities "public" and the problem disappeared.
Another solution would have been to create the mapping table myself in order to be able to keep everything "internal" and init it myself.